# French apostrophe char in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

i have a mysql table and some rows in a column contains `’` character. I have to echo the table content as xml. I am using this `utf8_encode($row['data'])` and the data is being responded as `Â’`. I have used iconv and also did try to do a `str_replace('’','somechar',$row['data'])` but its now working.

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/), [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all you need to do is `echo $row['data'];`, the data is in Windows-1252 and your page's headers are in Windows-1252 as well. No conversion
to UTF-8 required.

If you didn't realize your data is in windows-1252, and so have set `encoding="UTF-8"` in your xml, you shoiuld set it to `encoding="Windows-1252"`.

---

If you want to use UTF-8, you should first start by setting your connection to UTF-8:

```
mysql_set_charset( "utf8" );
// or $mysqli->set_charset( "utf8" );
```

Before you make any queries.

After that you need to fix your http headers:

```
<?php
header( "Content-type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

And of course, not call `utf8_decode`. Never call `utf8_decode` or `utf8_encode` unless you *really* know what you're doing. For starters, these functions work on ISO-8859-1->UTF-8 (and vice versa) conversions (the real ISO-8859-1, not the browser "ISO-8859-1" which is actually just Windows-1252) and are not some magic unicode wand.

There are many other things to do if you want to take utf-8 route, but these two will fix your immediate problem.